# A way to pass c++ object to another object's method in cython

Tags: python, c++, cython

I have two classes (let's assume the most simple ones, implementation is not important). My `defs.pxd` file (with cython defs) looks like this:

```
cdef extern from "A.hpp":
  cdef cppclass A:
    A() except +

cdef extern from "B.hpp":
  cdef cppclass B:
    B() except +
    int func (A)
```

My `pyx` file (with python defs) looks like this:

```
from cython.operator cimport dereference as deref
from libcpp.memory cimport shared_ptr

cimport defs

cdef class A:
    cdef shared_ptr[cquacker_defs.A] _this

    @staticmethod
    cdef inline A _from_this(shared_ptr[cquacker_defs.A] _this):
        cdef A result = A.__new__(A)
        result._this = _this
        return result

    def __init__(self):
        self._this.reset(new cquacker_defs.A())

cdef class B:
    cdef shared_ptr[cquacker_defs.B] _this

    @staticmethod
    cdef inline B _from_this(shared_ptr[cquacker_defs.B] _this):
        cdef B result = B.__new__(B)
        result._this = _this
        return result

    def __init__(self):
        self._this.reset(new cquacker_defs.B())

    def func(self, a):
      return deref(self._this).func(deref(a._this))
```

The thing is that `deref(self._this)` works right, but `deref(a._this)` doesn't with this error:

```
Invalid operand type for '*' (Python object)
```

How can I pass one python object's internal c++ object to another one's method in python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
def func(self, A a):
    return # ... as before
```

You need to tell Cython that `a` is of type `A` (the type is checked when you call it). That way it knows about `a._this` and doesn't treat it as a Python attribute lookup. You can only access `cdef`ed attributes if Cython knows the type at comple time.